# How can I scan a specific area of text for a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to scan a specific area of a string for a specific word, but i can not come up with anything.

For example:

```
given_word = 'I am setting this example for you to understand'

word_searching = 'for'
```

So for a reason that is not important i have to search in specific area.

```
given_word(5:10)
```

but if i write

```
if word_searching in given_word(5:10):
```

or

```
if word_searching in given_word(5,10):
```

I get errors. How can I fix this?Thanks in advance

Comment: hint: look for slicing operator!

Comment: do you want to use square brackets `[ ]` instead of `( )`. For example: `given_word[5:10]`

Comment: @DirtyBit thanks for the help just realized my mistake

Answer (score 4):

Using `given_word(5:10)` is a syntax error, you need to write `given_word[5:10]` with square brackets for slicing. Although, there is a better approach.

You can provide `start` and `stop` arguments to the [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method.

```
given_word = 'I am setting this example for you to understand'
given_word.find("for", 5, 10) # -1
given_word.find("for", 20, 30) # 26
```

The result will be `-1` if the sequence is not found, otherwise it will be the index where that sequence was found. In your case, you can use it like so:

```
given_word = 'I am setting this example for you to understand'

word_searching = 'for'

# Check if 'for' is found in the substring given_word[5:10]
if given_word.find(word_searching, 5, 10) != -1:
    ...
```

This is more efficient because slicing creates a new string while the `str.find` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use pattern searching with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
given_word = 'I am setting this example for you to understand'
word_searching = 'for'
# or:
# word_searching = r'fo.'

if re.findall(word_searching, given_word[0:10]):
    print('0:10')
elif re.findall(word_searching, given_word[20:30]):
    print('20:30')
else:
    print('not found')

# Prints:
# 20:30
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to search for `word_searching` in `given_word` words 5 through 10.

```
given_word = 'I am setting this example for you to understand'

word_searching = 'for'


if word_searching in given_word.split(' ')[5:10]:
  print(True)
```